# How to pipe input to Wireshark in Windows Power Shell?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, pipe, plink

I am trying to run the following command in Power Shell:

```
C:\Users\mne\Desktop\plink.exe -ssh -pw abc root@myhost "tcpdump -w - -U -i vethf90673c 'port 5000'" | &"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\Wireshark.exe" -k -i -
```

But Wireshark never starts, PowerShell just prints that tcpdump is listening.

How can I run it in Power Shell?

I have to mention that the command as shown works in CMD.

Comment: the answer here https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/23609/remote-capture-via-ssh-and-pipe doesn't use a `&` after the pipe, try this. but probably this is cygwin style. try this: `plink.exe -ssh -pw abc root@myhost "tcpdump -w - -U -i vethf90673c 'port 5000'" *>&1 | "C:\Program Files\Wireshark\Wireshark.exe" -k -i -`

Comment: @SimonS, nope, it does not work.

Comment: You are trying to pipe a DOS command to another DOS command one the PowerShell pipeline. That is really not a thing that you can do.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pipe a DOS command to another DOS command one the PowerShell pipeline. That is really not a thing that you can do. The pipe in CMD.exe is not the same as the pipe in PowerShell.

To use external .exe in with PowerShell, in most cases, they require special consideration and the use of the -Arguments parameter to handle any switches.

See details here:

> PowerShell: Running Executables
>
> There are several different methods for running executables as well as
>   invoking code. How do you know which one to use for the job? Here is
>   an outline of the methods with examples and general use.
>
> https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx
>
> http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right

Piping means you are passing and object to another cmdlet or the results of a cmdlet to another cmdlet. On the pipeline you can only match by property or by value.

More definitively detailed here:

> Two Ways To Accept Pipeline Input In PowerShell
>
> A pipeline in PowerShell is a series of values, expressions, commands
>   or cmdlets that are combined with the pipe operator (|) to send the
>   results of one command or expression to the next. These results are
>   sent through the pipeline as objects or object properties, not just
>   text as from the Windows command console (cmd.exe) or certain other
>   non-PowerShell methods. If the results consist of an array of objects,
>   these objects are sent in one-by-one through the pipeline.
>
> https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2016/11/21/two-ways-to-accept-pipeline-input-in-powershell

What you have here is two completely separate commands / exe's. So, in the PowerShell console host, you'd do this instead...

```
C:\Users\mne\Desktop\plink.exe -ssh -pw abc root@myhost "tcpdump -w - -U -i vethf90673c 'port 5000'" ; C:\Program Files\Wireshark\Wireshark.exe -k -i
```

That semi-colon tells PowerShell that these are separate commands that just happen to be on the same line, so, execute them as if they were on separate lines. You'll see this semi-colon use a lot when folks hammer out one liners in the powershell console host or the powershell_ise.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that removing the `-` from this command might help - in both places. It appears you have left it in somewhere.

`C:\Users\mne\Desktop\plink.exe -ssh -pw abc root@myhost "tcpdump -w - -U -i vethf90673c 'port 5000'" | "C:\Program Files\Wireshark\Wireshark.exe" -k -i -`

Comment: No. it is part of the command syntax.